# convert 3phase 220v into 3phase 165volt

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

I use a frequency converter which has an input of ONE phase 240 volt, 50hz.
This device gives me output from 200-240volt, 0-500hz and THREE phase.

The spindle motor I have needs input of 165 volt, up to 300hz.
This motor is connected in Y-format.[image]

I did make three tranformers and connected them in Y-format. It worked but not good enough and it is very very heavy[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcWTP.jpg)

Can you help me to solv this challange in an easier way? (Maybe without using tranformers)

This will be use in Norway (240v/50hz is standard).

Comment: get some wires with the correct colours for 3 phase.

Comment: If your using a Variable Frequency Drive (VFD) it may be able to reduce the output voltage for you.

Comment: It cannot reduce the voltage less than 200v! Jason, thank you for your notification. I will do that. This is only for testing.

Comment: Bad news: You need the matching Homag frequency converter, or more commonly known as a variable frequency drive or VFD for short. Do not put transformers between the VFD and the Motor. The VFD produces a lot of harmonics and has DC components that the VFD uses to control things like winding current and timing. The transformers can not handle this properly. Your only other approach is to hack the VFD and see if you can drop the DC bus voltage to the inverter portion. This can be done by using a separate input transformer for the DC bus to achieve a lower output voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those transformers are oversized, 330VA transformers for 300Hz use should be much smaller than that, and you don't need 300 VA transformers if you use autotransformers:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOkj11.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

the autotransformers only need to handle about 100VA and at 300 Hz

at 300hz the transformer core can be 1/6th the mass of a 50Hz transformer
and if you don't need isolation use autotransformers which will in this case give another reduction by a factor of 3

If you can biuld the three transformers on a three phase core that will save some iron too

[image]

Comment: Up to 300Hz though, that may include 10Hz. Where possibly peak current is also a thing. Anyway, definite +1 for suggesting a Auto-Trans set-up.

Comment: at lower frequencies the motor voltage will also need to be reduced. if you keep within the safe operating area for the motor you will also be in the safe operating area for the transformer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am trying to learn how to build auotranformers. Maybe I can use some part of laminated metal core of the old one! Either to cut one legg or only use the I-shape of it. Need to know/find out more about the detail.

Comment: they can be built like the ordinary transfromers I used in the diagram, one 55V winding and one 165V winding connected in series.  The 55V winding will carry most of the current: (about 1.6A) and the 165V winding will carry the rest (about 0.5A).   The easiest way to re-use would just be to use a thinner stack of laminations.  Also you could cut the centre leg  of the E down to the same width as the outer legs and build a 3 phase transformer with one phase wound on each leg.

Comment: @Jasen Makes sense. Consider me shut up. :-)

Comment: Reading your comment gave me a better understanding of autotransformer. I am going to use your sudgested solution and re-use of old parts. Question: Having all three phases on same E-shape wouldn't cause interference of one magnetic fields(one phase) on other phases? I gave also masured the E-shape dimentions. It has leg length=68mm, leg width=22.5mm, length of E-base 135mm and depth=58mm. It gives me an inne core dimention of 22.5x58x45.5mm. Is it ok or should I increase or decreas it?

Comment: it will cause them to interact, but so long as all the windings face the same direction the interaction will not be harmful. this construction is common in iindustry eg: http://www.boardman-transformers.co.uk/assets/img/product/3-Phase-0-5-160kVA-1.jpg

Comment: I did calculate the area after smalling down the width of center legg of E-shape. What I discovered was that I nee 3.6 turn/volt. It  means 197 and 592 turns. 789 turns needs more space between the E-legs! Should I weld a new E-shape out of solid core metal? Or any other suggestion?

Comment: maybe use a thicker stack of laminations that will result in a proportionally lower turns count needed.